# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model> Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please Help mvc Controler idk convert stuf i have no idea ! what is wrong in this code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);
    DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Today;
    List<Transaction>
        SelectedTransaction = await _context.Transaction.
        Include(x => x.Category)
        .Where(y => y.Date > StartDate && y.Date < EndDate)
        .ToListAsync();
    return View();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error message describes your problem clearly and unambiguously.

You have two `Transaction` types. One is defined in the `Expose_Tracker.Models` namespace and the second in the `System.Transactions`namespace.

Therefore when you are preparing  the `List<Transaction>` it is necessary to convert from the `System.Transactions.Transaction` type to  the `<Expose_Tracker.Models.Transaction` type.

I suppose it should be like below:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    List<Transaction> selectedTransaction = 
            await _context.Transaction
                     .Include(x => x.Category)
                     .Where(y => y.Date > StartDate && y.Date < EndDate)
                     .Select( t => new Expose_Tracker.Models.Transaction
                         {
                           ... assign required properties 
                         })
                     .ToListAsync();

    // And probably this collection will be passed as data model to the    view
    return View(selectedTransaction); 
}
```

Comment: Still not bro   await _context.Transaction(S) not Transaction ihave no idea why

Comment: @MuneerZaatreh: Add the new updated code to your post. Just mark it **_Updated:_**, for example. This is very simple problem, but I can't help without view your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Is not the good idea to use the name of net classes as a custom class name, you have  a name space overlapping.Try

```
List<Expose_Tracker.Models.Transaction> selectedTransaction =  await _context.Transaction .... and so on

    // And probably 
    return View(selectedTransaction);
```

or just use var

```
var selectedTransaction =  await _context.Transaction .... and so on
```